# How to force RPM to install a package and NOT replace files that conflict

Tags: centos7, rpm

I've got an older vendor-supplied package that I'm trying to install on CentOS 7. It installs things into /usr/lib, but there's a conflict with the /usr/lib directory itself.

The /usr/lib directory as installed:

```
ls -ld /usr/lib
dr-xr-xr-x. 42 root root 4096 Jun 10 08:44 /usr/lib
```

The /usr/lib directory as specified in the package:

```
rpm -qlpv <package file>
drwxr-xr-x    2 root    root  0 Jun 22  2006 /usr/lib
```

I could use --replacefiles with rpm to get it to go on, but that's not actually the RIGHT thing to do here. Instead, I'd like rpm to just skip installing the /usr/lib directory (it's already there, after all), and just install the contents.

The --excludepath option doesn't actually seem to do anything (I still get the error), and (according to -vv output) would exclude most of the package anyway.

For the moment, in a test environment, I can do --replacefiles, but I feel there must be some 'more correct' way to deal with this situation.

NOTE: Getting an updated vendor package IS on my TODO list, but isn't going to happen for some time, so I need a better near-term solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest installing it into another directory with `rpm --prefix` and pull out the stuff you need. Alternatively, you could extract it directly with `rpm2pcio package.rpm | cpio -idmv`.

Using `--prefix` does at least have the benefit of executing any post-install scripts, etc... in the RPM.

Hope the helps!

Comment: OK, prefix is certainly workable. I can then move everything afterwards myself. Not perfect, because then I can't uninstall using rpm, but at least it doesn't break things.

Comment: It still exists in the RPM DB when you use `--prefix`, so you can erase the record. If memory serves, I think it will remove the files also as long as you also specify prefix with `rpm -e`. Same applies if upgrading.

Comment: Just one caveat to keep in mind.  Not all rpm's are relocatable using `--prefix`.  In those cases, you whould need to extract using the rpm2cpio method that was mentioned.  Just something you might run into.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that if I can't get a vendor update, I might simply pull the rpm apart and rebuild it, with proper attributes on /usr/lib. I'll have to see if it actually uses any scripts.